# How change the default separator of opencsv?

Tags: java, opencsv

First of all, hello and sorry for the beginner question but I already saw the documentation and tutorials but I can't make it work on my code. Maybe I'm making a little mistake but I can't catch it.

*I'm using the latest version of opencsv in a maven project.* So I need to make a .csv file and for that I use:

```
try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("file.csv", true)) {
    /* code
}
```

And everything works fine, but I need to use a diferent separator, so I try with:

```
try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("file.csv", true), '-') {
    /* code
}
```

But appears **Cannot resolve constructor 'CSVWriter(java.io.FileWriter, char)'** in IntelliJ, when in the documentation says [opencsv documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ4xA.png)

Any idea on how fix it? (Sorry for my english, I'm not native speaker).

Comment: Java 13, Maven 3.6.3 and opencsv 5.2 (is the latest in the maven repository)

Comment: Intellij is not able to resolve it, and the compiler?

Comment: Says java: no suitable constructor found for CSVWriter(java.io.FileWriter,char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the constructor is either just the file or 5 parameters, so you cannot have just 2:
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html

Comment: Haha thank you so much!, that was my mistake. I swear read better the next time.